# How to override the default Host request header using Jetty HTTP Client v9?

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am using Jetty client v9 to issue requests to a server. The address of the server I specify has to be in the form of actual (numeric) IP address for various reasons not important for this question, but I would like to pass the assumed host name (i.e. FQDN, not numeric) in the Host header. I've tried the following:

```
request = httpClient.newRequest(url);
request.method(HttpMethod.GET);
...
request.header(HttpHeader.HOST, hostHeader);
```

But found that this has no effect. The value of the "Host" header included in the actual request is still the one from the URL (containing the numeric IP address). I did verify that 'hostHeader' variable above does contain the correct value (that I would want).

Can anyone provide some insight as to how to override this default behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is correct, and the value you specify via the header overwrites the one specified in the URI, as expected.

I just committed a [test case](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=6f87a9b9955ca07bc21a950aa7c1042be906246a) that captures the use case you described, and works for me.

Perhaps you have a more complex examples that triggers a corner case, and it will be helpful if you can write a reproducible test case. If that is the case, please submit an issue at the [Jetty Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty).